# Show/Hide Fields Based on Name?

Tags: custom-object, page-layout

In my `Financial Account` custom object, certain sections are there, only one relevant to a particular `Account Name`, at a time, others being irrelevant.

Is there a procedure that on the basis of `Name`, I could make only that section appear on detail page, which is relevant for that particular record?

Comment: How many different names are we talking about? Is `Account Name` a field on Financial Account object?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change the `RecordType` based on the contents of the `Name` field. This `Field Update` can be implemented via `Workflow Rule`. Then you can tailor a `Page Layout` to each specific `RecordType`.